# multiple binding of input using react but with exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Sorry I just don't know how to explain it in one line, so the title is a little bit confusing.

http://jsbin.com/dipajegoqo/1/edit

```
 handleInput(e) {
    this.setState({
      main_price: e.target.value
    })

  }

  render() {
    return (      
      <div>
          <div><input onChange={this.handleInput.bind(this)} type="text" /></div>
          <div><input onChange={e => this.setState({discounted: e.target.value})} value={this.state.main_price} type="text" name="" /></div>
          <input onChange={e => this.setState({discounted: e.target.value})} value={this.state.main_price} type="text" name="" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What I want is I want to have a main input, that when onChange it will update all the other inputs. In my example the first one is the main input, it worked when I set `value={this.state.main_price}` to other inputs, but now the problem is other inputs can't have their own value because it's tie to main_price state. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is easy, you need to have different state values for the different inputs and you need to set them when the emain input value change like

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      main_price: '',
      discounted: ''
    }
  }

  handleInput(e) {
    this.setState({
      main_price: e.target.value,
      val1: e.target.value,
      val2: e.target.value
    })

  }

  render() {
    return (      
      <div>
          <div><input onChange={this.handleInput.bind(this)} type="text" /></div>
          <div><input onChange={e => this.setState({discounted: e.target.value, val1:e.target.value})} value={this.state.val1} type="text" name="" /></div>

          <input onChange={e => this.setState({discounted: e.target.value, val2: e.target.value})} value={this.state.val2} type="text" name="" />


      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(
  <HelloWorldComponent name="Joe Schmoe"/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);


[JSBIN][1]
```

Comment: this is not the solution for my problem, I want to avoid declaring bunch of states.

Comment: @AlanJenshen , if you want controlled input then you need to make use of separate state to store the input value.

Comment: actually I got your point, it's matter of formatting, thanks mate!

Comment: anyway I'm stuck at using ${} for dynamic setState, can you help here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676995/dynamic-state-using-es6-snytax-failed

Comment: Did you check the other answer as well

Comment: other answer? you're the only one answered my question.

Comment: I meant the answer on your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675823/single-handler-on-multiple-listener-on-react/43676220#43676220