# Single handler on multiple listener on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Were trying to use es6 to make dynamic state without multiple handlers but I'm stuck. I've no clue what's wrong with my code below

```
<div className="row-wrap">
    <span>Mon</span>
    <input name="1_min" onChange={this.handleAdvancePrice} type="text" />
    <input name="1_max" onChange={this.handleAdvancePrice} type="text" />
</div>
<div className="row-wrap">
    <span>Tue</span>
    <input name="2_min" onChange={this.handleAdvancePrice} type="text" />
    <input name="2_max" onChange={this.handleAdvancePrice} type="text" />
</div>

<button onClick={this.showStates}></button>

..
..

handleAdvancePrice = (e) => {

    let dow = e.target.name.split('_')[0],
    type = e.target.name.split('_')[1],
    value = +(e.target.value);

    console.log(dow, type) // it print correctly

    this.setState = ({
        [`advancePrice_${dow}_${type}`]: value
    })
}

showStates = () => {
    console.log(this.state) //error this.setState is not a function, caused by handleAdvancePrice
}
```

I've checked my other function, handleAdvancePrice is the culprit, but what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the culprit is the extra `=` sign after `this.setState`. Also there is not need to use `type and dow` separate;y since it is available to you directly with `e.target.name`

```js
class  App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {}
}

handleAdvancePrice = (e) => {

    let dow = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;
    
    this.setState ({
        [`advancePrice_${dow}`]: value
    })
}

showStates = () => {
    console.log(this.state) //error this.setState is not a function, caused by handleAdvancePrice
}

render() {

return (
<div>
<div className="row-wrap">
    <span>Mon</span>
    <input name="1_min" onChange={this.handleAdvancePrice} type="text" />
    <input name="1_max" onChange={this.handleAdvancePrice} type="text" />
</div>
<div className="row-wrap">
    <span>Tue</span>
    <input name="2_min" onChange={this.handleAdvancePrice} type="text" />
    <input name="2_max" onChange={this.handleAdvancePrice} type="text" />
</div>

<button onClick={this.showStates}>Show</button>
</div>
)
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: check this answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not binding the proper context to your function `handleAdvancePrice`.

If you are building your component using ES6 Class then, you can bind the context to all your functions in constructor like this:

```
constructor() {
   this.handleAdvancePrice = this.handleAdvancePrice.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you case event delegation should help. Instead of binding multiple event handlers for every input, bind single one on the common parent container:

```
<div className="container" onChange={this.handleAdvancePrice}>
    <div className="row-wrap">
        <span>Mon</span>
        <input name="1_min" type="text" />
        <input name="1_max" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div className="row-wrap">
        <span>Tue</span>
        <input name="2_min" type="text" />
        <input name="2_max" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in `handleAdvancePrice` you can check for proper event target, it should be input elements, i.e. `e.target.tagName === 'INPUT'`, and proceed in this case. But if you don't have other form elements within this container, you don't even need this check, because `onChange` event can only originate from form elements and if you only have inputs, you are fine and `handleAdvancePrice` stays untouched.