# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined - React

Tags: reactjs

I can not figure out if I am missing something small here?

Just trying to get a grasp on how state works with React.

Just creating a small check box that changes text on check/uncheck.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Basic extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            checked: true
        };
    }

    handleCheck() {
        this.setState = ({
            checked: !this.state.checked
        });
    }

    render() {
        var msg;
        if (this.state.checked) {
            msg = 'checked'
        } else {
            msg = 'unchecked'
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheck} defaultChecked={this.state.checked} />
                <h3>Checkbox is {msg}</h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: because you forgot to `bind` the onChange method, use this: `onChange={this.handleCheck.bind(this)}` or bind the method in the constructor.

Comment: So I added that then I got this "Uncaught TypeError: inst.setState.bind is not a function"

Comment: can you show what you changed ? you don't need to bind the setState  you need to bind the onChange method like i suggested in above comment, just replace the onChange method with the above line.

Comment: render() {
     var msg;
     if(this.state.checked) {
      msg = 'checked'
     }else {
      msg = 'unchecked'
     }
     return (
      <div>
       <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheck.bind(this)} defaultChecked={this.state.checked} />
       <h3>Checkbox is {msg}</h3>
      </div>
     );
    }

Comment: you used setState in awrong way, remove **=** in this line: `this.setState = ({` it should be  `this.setState({ `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single handler on multiple listener on react](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675823/single-handler-on-multiple-listener-on-react)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changes:

**1.** You forgot to bind the `onChange` method, either use this:

`onChange={this.handleCheck.bind(this)}`

or define the binding in the `constructor`:

`this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this)`

**2.** You used `setState` in a wrong way, setState is a method you need to call it.

Instead of: `this.setState = ({})`

it should be: `this.setState({})`

Answer (score 5):

Binding your `handleCheck` function in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        checked: true
    };

    this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: This also works for sure. If this truly does, please consider an up-vote for my answer, although another one has been accepted, thanks ^^

Comment: in some cases, binding in the constructor can make for cleaner code, but binding on the function call can be easier to understand. both work the same, but it's always nice to see all your binding stacked neatly in the constructor.