# React-Formal onSubmit form not resetting / setting state

Tags: ajax, forms, reactjs

I'm very new to React and I'm really struggling to "reset" a form after a successful AJAX submission. Please note, no Redux.
The values/set do not reset to empty after submission and the button (which I want to disable after a successful submission) does not get disabled either.

I'm using [React-Formal](https://github.com/jquense/react-formal) for validation, and that is perhaps breaking the usual "onSubmit" behavior for the form, due to the Form using a custom `<Form>` tag.

I've tried binding a
`.bind(this)`to the AJAX form and disable the inputs and button with a `this.setState` object, setting all the inputs to `value : ''` and `disabled: true` for the button and similar methods, but React does not recognize the `setState` function inside AJAX function, even if I call another function inside the success that is outside of the AJAX scope.

Please note that I set individual `onChange` behaviors for every input, as setting a one-for-all function would not work, probably because of the validation.

I'd really appreciate if you could help me out, as I've been struggling with this for days and nothing seems to work. I'd like to use React, but I'll have to disable the button with JQuery if it doesn't work, something which I'd like to avoid.

Thanks for your help! Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Form from 'react-formal';
import Yup from 'yup';
import $ from 'jquery';

var modelSchema = Yup.object({

  firstname: Yup.string().required('First name is required'),
  lastname: Yup.string().required('Last name is required'),
  phone: Yup.string().min(6, 'Phone is too short'),
  phone: Yup.string().matches(/^[\+0-9\-_\/]+$/, 'Phone is not valid'),
  phone: Yup.string().required('Phone is required')

});

var formData = {};

class FormStep1 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
       firstname: '',
       lastname: '',
       phone: '',
       disabled: false
      }

      this.handlePhoneChange = this.handlePhoneChange.bind(this);
      this.handleFirstNameChange = this.handleFirstNameChange.bind(this);
      this.handleLastNameChange = this.handleLastNameChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

   handlePhoneChange(value) {
        this.setState({phone: value});
    }

   handleFirstNameChange(value) {
        this.setState({firstname: value});
    } 

   handleLastNameChange(value) {
        this.setState({lastname: value});
    }

   handleSubmit(e, message) {

    formData = {
        phone: this.state.phone,
        firstname: this.state.firstname,
        lastname: this.state.lastname
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: //some URL,
        headers: {
            //some header
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        success: function () {
            this.setState({
                firstname: '',
                lastname: '',
                phone: '',
                disabled: true
            })
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    })

  }



  render() {
    return (
      <Form role="form" schema={modelSchema} id="phoneForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className='row'>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <label htmlFor="phone">Phone</label><br />
          <Form.Field id="phone" className="form-control" placeholder="Phone" onChange={this.handlePhoneChange} name="phone" value={this.state.phone} />
          <Form.Message for='phone'/>
        </div>

        <div className='form-group'>
          <label htmlFor="firstname">Name</label><br />
          <Form.Field id="firstname" className="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange} name="firstname" value={this.state.firstname} />
          <Form.Message for='firstname'/>
        </div>

        <div className='form-group'>
          <label htmlFor="lastname">&nbsp;</label><br />
          <Form.Field id="lastname" className="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" onChange={this.handleLastNameChange} name="lastname" value={this.state.lastname} />
          <Form.Message for='lastname'/>
        </div>

        <Form.Button className="btn btn-green btn-block" disabled={this.state.disabled} type="submit">Submit</Form.Button>            
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

export default FormStep1;
```

UPDATE: Added the correct `.bind(this)` to the AJAX success. The button is correctly disabled after submitting now. But the input fields are still showing the value I submitted after clicking the button. They are not resetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not bind the ajax success method where you are actually resetting the inputs

```
handleSubmit(e, message) {
    e.preventDefault();
    formData = {
        phone: this.state.phone,
        firstname: this.state.firstname,
        lastname: this.state.lastname
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: //some URL,
        headers: {
            //some header
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        success: function () {
            this.setState({
                firstname: '',
                lastname: '',
                phone: '',
                disabled: true
            })
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            alert('Error');
        }.bind(this)
    })

  }
```

Also just to improve on your code, you don't need  a separate handler for all inputs

Refer these answers: [Is there a neater way to connect an input field to a state property in React than onChange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714596/is-there-a-neater-way-to-connect-an-input-field-to-a-state-property-in-react-tha/43714677#43714677)  and [Single handler on multiple listener on react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675823/single-handler-on-multiple-listener-on-react/43676220#43676220)

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing that out! Indeed, the button is disabled now. But the input fields still show the value that I typed after submitting. How can I reset the input to show it empty?

Comment: You are setting the value through state which you have reset in ajax call, it should reset the state

Comment: Use preventDefault on handle
Submit too

Comment: That's the thing, the value is still there after submitting, even though the button gets disabled correctly.

Comment: and preventDefault and see , check the updated answer

Comment: I get "Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function"

Comment: check for the event from console.log(e, message), I think the oreder the variables can be the issue here

Comment: after console.log(e, message) -> "Object {phone: "312313", lastname: "dadasda", firstname: "sadasdsad"} undefined", any ideas on how to make the preventDefault work? And would that not prevent the form from being actually submitted?